# Load a dynamic shared library (DLL) on Mac in C++ using CFBundleCreate

Tags: c++, macos, dll, frameworks, cfbundleidentifier

How do I implement a function to load a dll(aka framework) on Mac OS using C++? 

`void LoadFramework(const char* frameworkPath)
{
  //frameworkPath is the absolute path of the framework
}`

**Edit:**
When I google searched for this problem, I mostly ended up with dlopen solution to load the framework. What I am instead looking for is to use **CFBundleCreate** to load the framework. It seems to me that there are a bunch of methods needed to be called to construct an URL from const char * path. I found the needed code in pieces, and could not write one comprehensive solution.

Comment: A Google search for "load shared library mac" brings up a link to developer.apple.com that discussed that particular topic, and specifically mentions the library function that does this. Have you tried doing some research on this by doing a Google search? What did you find, and which part of the documentation do you have specific questions about?

Comment: Based on the above comment by @Sam, I will edit my question now to be more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It typically is just a few lines of straightforward code to open a framework in Mac, something along the lines of :

```
bundleURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,
    CFSTR("/System/Library/Frameworks/<your_framework_name.framework>"),
    kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);

bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundleURL);
assert(bundle != NULL);
```

and pretty much everything in that snippet is well documented. I would suggest adding more detail in the question, as to the specifics of what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: yeah, this code is what I finally ended up writing last week. Thanks!
I tend to disagree that everything in this snippet is well documented. It was not quite that easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
using DLL_Namespace;
```

This should give you access to the DLL.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you expand on your answer a bit? How is this line used in the context of the question? Can you provide an example for how this would work?